# parsing and evaluating arbirtary equations with python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to separate data from code in a python project. The data consists of pandas DataFrames and equations linking the DataFrame columns.

Currently, I have hard-coded the equations within my script so I can't dynamically change them (load in run-time new DataFrames and corresponding equations). Any suggestions on how to generate equivalent functions?

E.g:

```
#Given a pandas data frame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns= ["a", "b", "c"])

# and a simple arbitrary expression such as:
equation1 ="a + 2*a/b"

#how to dynamically create a function equivalent to:
def f(df):
  return(df['a']+2*df['a']/df['b']) # hard-coded equation 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
equation1 ="a + 2*a/b"
print (df.eval(equation1))
0    2.00
1    5.60
2    8.75
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can assign it back to the dataframe with assign

```
df.assign(eq1=df.eval(equation1))

   a  b  c   eq1
0  1  2  3  2.00
1  4  5  6  5.60
2  7  8  9  8.75
```

You can make it even more dynamic using a dictionary of equations

```
deq = dict(
    EQ1='a + 2 * a / b',
    EQ2='c ** 2 / (a + b)'
)
df.assign(**{k: df.eval(v) for k, v in deq.items()})

   a  b  c   EQ1  EQ2
0  1  2  3  2.00  3.0
1  4  5  6  5.60  4.0
2  7  8  9  8.75  5.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution [similar to @piRSquared's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43373089/5741205), which allows to evaluate multiple equations in one step:

```
In [442]: equations = """
     ...: EQ1 = a + 2 * a / b
     ...: EQ2 =c ** 2 / (a + b)
     ...: """

In [443]: df.eval(equations, inplace=False)
Out[443]:
   a  b  c   EQ1  EQ2
0  1  2  3  2.00  3.0
1  4  5  6  5.60  4.0
2  7  8  9  8.75  5.4
```

NOTE: it's better to use multi-line expressions - in this case you can use previously calculated variables

Demo:

```
In [444]: equations = """
     ...: EQ1 = a + 2 * a / b
     ...: EQ2 = EQ1**2
     ...: """

In [445]: df.eval(equations, inplace=False)
Out[445]:
   a  b  c   EQ1      EQ2
0  1  2  3  2.00   4.0000
1  4  5  6  5.60  31.3600
2  7  8  9  8.75  76.5625
```